# CSS3 border radius to HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I trying to reproduce the CSS3 border radius in canvas.

It's easy to draw a rounded rectangle but in CSS, the value of each border can be high.

For example : 
**HTML**

```
<div class="normal_radius"></div>
<div class="high_radius"></div>
<div class="high2_radius"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div { height:50px;width:50px;position:absolute;top:10px; }
.normal_radius {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 10px 15px;
    left: 10px;
}
.high_radius {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 5000px 500px 100px 150px;
    left: 80px;
}
.high2_radius {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 2500px 250px 50px 75px;
    left: 160px;
}
```

Here a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fAJ9t/)

The black, normal border radius value, i can reproduce that.
The red, high value for border radius, i don't know how reproduce that.
And the blue, high value divided by 2, same result of red.

My question is simple, how to reproduce the red and the blue in canvas?

Best regards.

Comment: i think you have to use the path methods to draw the curve by your self. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes scroll down to "moveTo" and "Bezier and quadratic curves"

Comment: Just a question: why use those huge values for `border-radius` in your CSS when `border-radius: 100% 10% 0 0;` gives you the same effect?http://jsfiddle.net/fAJ9t/66/

Comment: Hi, thank for you answer but i know the method to draw rounded rectangle, i want the algorithm/formule to draw rounded rectangle if the user enters high value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function below is pretty close. Although if you use values greater than the width and height you're going to have issues.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fAJ9t/74/)**

```
function canvasRadius(x, y, w, h, tl, tr, br, bl){
  var r = x + w,
      b = y + h;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x+tl, y);
  ctx.lineTo(r-(tr), y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(r, y, r, y+tr);
  ctx.lineTo(r, b-br);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(r, b, r-br, b);
  ctx.lineTo(x+bl, b);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, b, x, b-bl);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y+tl);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x+tl, y);
  ctx.stroke();

}

canvasRadius(10,10,50,50,5,5,10,15);
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
canvasRadius(80,10,50,50,47,3,0,0);
ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
canvasRadius(160,10,50,50,47,3,0,0);
```

Comment: Hi, in the W3C web site, i found that : 

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-overlap

But i don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

here the solution :

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.roundRect=function(x,y,width,height,tl,tr,br,bl) {
  var x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,radii,ratio=0,CURVE2KAPPA=0.5522847498307934;
  ratio=Math.min(Math.min(width/(tl+tr),width/(br+bl)),Math.min(height/(tl+bl),height/(tr+br)));
  if ((ratio>0)&&(ratio<1)) {
    tl*=ratio;
    tr*=ratio;
    bl*=ratio;
    br*=ratio;
  }
  xw=x+width;
  yh=y+height;
  x1=x+tl;
  x2=xw-tr;
  x3=xw-br;
  x4=x+bl;
  y1=y+tr;
  y2=yh-br;
  y3=yh-bl;
  y4=y+tl;
  this.beginPath();
  this.moveTo(x1,y);
  this.lineTo(x2,y);
  radii=CURVE2KAPPA*tr;
  this.bezierCurveTo(x2+radii,y,xw,y1-radii,xw,y1);
  this.lineTo(xw,y2);
  radii=CURVE2KAPPA*br;
  this.bezierCurveTo(xw,y2+radii,x3+radii,yh,x3,yh);
  this.lineTo(x4,yh);
  radii=CURVE2KAPPA*bl;
  this.bezierCurveTo(x4-radii,yh,x,y3+radii,x,y3);
  this.lineTo(x,y4);
  radii=CURVE2KAPPA*tl;
  this.bezierCurveTo(x,y4-radii,x1-radii,y,x1,y);
  this.stroke();
}

ctx.roundRect(0,0,50,50,5,5,10,15);
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
ctx.roundRect(0,0,50,50,5000,500,100,150);
ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
ctx.roundRect(0,0,50,50,2500,250,50,75);
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gy9Ed/1/)**

Have fun.